# continuous martingale are always bounded?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

Consider a continous martingale $M_t$ for $t \in [0,T]$.

Since each path $M(w)$ is bounded, I can take the maximum of the bounds for each path to deduce that M is bounded uniformly.

Why do I need the concept of local boundedness then?
My textbook suggests you should consider the stopping time $\tau_k =\inf\{t \in [0,T] : M_t\geq k\}$ to make an continuous martinagle at least locally bounded.
But why do I need that since I can get a upper bound for all paths?

Is there anything wrong with my first argumentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument tells you that for each $\omega$ there exists $C(\omega) < \infty$ such that for $t \in [0,T]$, $M_t(\omega) \leq C(\omega)$. Taking suprema as you suggest would yield $\sup_\omega \sup_{t \in [0,T]} M_t(\omega) \leq \sup_\omega C(\omega)$. You do not know a priori that the right hand side is finite.

Comment: But why can I not take the maximum of all bounds that I get for each path.

Comment: @Alif see my edit which hopefully makes this clearer to you. You can certainly take suprema but you have no way of knowing that the supremum of the bounds is not just $\infty$.

Comment: But if $C(\omega)$ is finite, why should the supremum be infinite?

Comment: Brownian motion is a continuous martingale which is obviously not bounded since at every $t$ it is normally distributed.

Comment: The supremum of an infinite set may be infinite.  For example the infinite set $\{1,2,3,\dots\}$.  In this case, there is one bound for each $\omega$, and the set $\Omega$ of all those $\omega$s is infinite.

Comment: @KurtG. I suggest you write that as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Brownian motion is a continuous martingale which is obviously not bounded since at every $t$ it is normally distributed and a normally distributed variable is unbounded.